# Unable to deserialize current JSON array due to field name

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, .net-4.5

I have json (simplified version)

```
var json = @"{""$type"": ""some type"",""$values"": [{""type"": ""some type"",""Name"": """",""Id"": ""someValue"",}]}";
```

```
public class JsonStorage
{
    [JsonProperty("$type")] public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("$values")] public List<JsonTest> Values { get; set; }
}

public class JsonTest
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")] public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Id")] public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

When deserialize

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonStorage>(json);
```

Throw exception

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Program+JsonStorage' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '$values', line 1, position 34.
```

If replace in json string `$type` -> `type` and `$values` -> `values` and set json property for that json, `DeserializeObject` works fine. I can use that way, replace before deserialization. But maybe there is a better option.

example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxZitW

Comment: Just looking at it, my guess is your string is jacked up. @"{""$type"": - The @ symbol says take my string as it is. Then you have double quotation marks. So the JSON converter is probably puking because it doesn't know what to do. Try removing the double quotations Like I said, just a guess based on what you posted

Comment: `@"_""_" == "_\"_"`

Comment: @AnthonyRussell I think Genusatplay is trying to say that doubling `"` is a way to escape it in an `@ string` .. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAAKP.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't encounter any problems deserializing the posted data, using the classes that http://quicktype.io made for me when pasting your json in (though it doesn't like the trailing comma)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3cs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var json = @"{""$type"": ""some type"",""$values"": [{""type"": ""some type"",""Name"": """",""Id"": ""someValue"",}]}";
            var rootClassNameHere = RootClassNameHere.FromJson(json);
        }
    }



    public partial class RootClassNameHere
    {
        [JsonProperty("$type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("$values")]
        public Value[] Values { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Value
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class RootClassNameHere
    {
        public static RootClassNameHere FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClassNameHere>(json, WindowsFormsApp3cs.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this RootClassNameHere self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, WindowsFormsApp3cs.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```